# How to correlate json data using JMeter correlation

Tags: json, jmeter, correlation

I am facing problem in `Jmeter correlation`, how to correlate data in JSON

```
{"type":"PostSectionData","sectionID":"76","sectionKeyName":"KYCVerification","ApplicationID":${AppId_g1},"userID":"6","androidApplicationID":"1000","staticvalues":"[{\"KeyName\":\"AadhaarNo\",\"AadhaarNo\":\"999922220032\",\"SubTitleValue\":\"null\"},{\"KeyName\":\"AadharCard\",\"AadharCard\":\"\\\/sdcard\\\/TestData\\\/999922220032.jpg\",\"SubTitleValue\":\"\"},{\"KeyName\":\"PAN\",\"PAN\":\"\",\"SubTitleValue\":\"null\"}]","dynamicvalues":"[]","syncFlag":"false","kycSyncFlag":"false"}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

Usually people use [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) to do JSON correlation.

References:

- [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (scroll down to "Parsing JSON")

Also you can use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), i.e. to extract "type" value apply the following configuration:

- Reference name: anything meaningful, i.e. `type`
- Regular Expression: `"type": "(.+?)"`
- Template: `$1$`

Refer extracted value as `${type}` where required.

You can evaluate your regular expressions using RegExp Tester mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

[image: View Results Tree Regexp]

If you have any further queries update your question with full response (above JSON is not valid) and what values you need to extract from it.

Comment: Thanks... But i am getting error in application Id is initially zero then after ekyc application Id value dynamically change  I have try json path extractor & also how to test rest API in Jemeter

Comment: Basically as any other HTTP application, just make sure you add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send at least `Content-Type` header with the value of `application/json`. See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for details